# How to show field inside another field in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What I want is to create a sales page that has dynamic content that I have to get from the database.
For example, I have a product model that has a content field that show html and I would like to show the price that is in another field inside of the content.

I would appreciate any recommendations.
I would prefer to use just Rails but I think that it may be impossible, so a jQuery solution would be great as well.

Comment: You mean that you save html in the content field, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, Helen

Comment: I think the only way is to either regex out the content from the string in Ruby or use jQuery's selector engine to obtain it via class, id, or other unique attribute.

Comment: Please have a look at this thread: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/148509
Good luck!

Comment: @CWitty, your regex suggestion seems to be a good approach. I will start to try it now. If you want to create an answer, I will accept it. If you don't, I will answer it after I implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to either regex out the content from the string in Ruby or use jQuery's selector engine to obtain it via class, id, or other unique attribute.